# heroku logs --tail error status 404 on get/post request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, heroku, multer

Whenever I make a post request on my heroku app it responds with a 404 status. What am i am missing in my code to get it to post/get sucessfully? here is the error when i enter heroku logs -tail:

```
2021-04-14T03:50:52.076702+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/thumbnail_image0.jpg" host=thawing-bastion-89215.herokuapp.com request_id=9bdfae76-50dc-4221-8567-2bfa2f714ab0 fwd="73.189.169.17" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=442 protocol=https
```

on my browser i get an error which says

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

locally my post request responds sucessfully with a status 200. and here is my post request on the front end onclick.

```
handleRequest = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const data = new FormData();
    const {file} = this.state
     data.append('file', file)
      

    axios.post('/api/user/myimages',data,{ 'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',headers: { 'authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')}})
    .then((response)=>{
        const {fileName,filePath} = response.data
        this.setState({uploadedFile:response.data})
        this.getMyImage()
        console.log(response,'postfdsv')
    })
       
}
```

for the backend i use express and multer.

```
const multer = require('multer')

const upload = multer({dest:''}) 


  router.route('/myimages')
 .get(requireAuth,getMyImages)
 .post(requireAuth,upload.single('file'),postMyImages)

 postMyImages: async (req, res) => {
    const { fileName,filePath } = req.body;
    console.log(req.files,'req files data postMyImages')

    if(req.files === null) {
      return res.status(400).json({msf:'no file uploaded'})
    }

    try {
      const file = req.files.file

      file.mv(`${__dirname}/../client/public/images/${file.name}`,async (err)=>{
        if(err){
          console.error(err)
          return res.status(500).send(err)
        }
        
        const newImage = await new Image({fileName:file.name,filePath:`/images/${file.name}`, user: req.user._id}).save();
        req.user.myImages.push(newImage);
        await req.user.save();
        return res.status(200).json(newImage);

        // res.json({fileName:file.name,filePath:`./images/${file.name}`})
      })}catch (e) {
      return res.status(403).json({ e });
    }


      // const newImage = await new Image({ fileName, user: req.user._id }).save();
      // const newStock = await Stock.create({ text, user: req.user._id });
      // req.user.myImages.push(newImage);
     
  }
```

Comment: Is your fronted and backend both hosted on Heroku?

Comment: @fortunee yeah, it is!